# laravel session changes data in already stored variable

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session, laravel-4

The idea is to compare data in session against a database data, but it always returns `0`, because of `Session::put('new', $arr);` when I remove it and change `$arr` data it works perfectly. What could be the reason? How does session can change data in previously stored variable?

```
        $arr = array('1','3','4');

        $sess = Session::get('new',array());
        $diff = array_diff($sess, $arr);

        Session::put('new', $arr);
        return count($diff);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Change `new` key in session? Change `$arr` according to session? It is not clear.

Comment: I use this to show new messages count. Arr gives ids from database with latest messages, then it compares them to session stored ones. But for some reason Session::put changed already stored $sess variable

Comment: I don't think `Session::put` is doing anything to `$sess`. It could be somewhere else in your code. Anyway, you are saving `$arr` in session key `new`, so on the next request, if there is no new notifications, the session and database have identical values. You are not talking about next request are you? You can put `var_dump` for `$arr`,`$sess`,`$diff` to see their values (or use a debugger). That should light things a bit more. Post the result here if you can.

Comment: Are you sure there is a difference $sess and $arr?